# to precision -- meaning?

Tags: comprehension

[Link to the YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2A8fi0X23Jc&list=PL0170B6E7DD6D8810&index=40#t=1m17s)

Transcript:

> Alright. So, you're probably wondering what the difference between the float, the double and the long double is. Well, the float is the least precise, meaning that it can store the least amount of digits. The float can only store six digits **to precision**. So, that means that we can only store a number with six digits inside of any float variable.

How do you guys understand that? What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We normally say *of precision*, not to precision. It is referring to the accuracy of the number. So, 6 digits of precision would be something like .333333

Answer (score 1):

> six digits **to precision.**

precisely 6 digits. But other digits will not guaranteed to be exactly like those 6 digits. Most of the time it will be round up.

Answer (score 0):

In that programming scenario, it means that float can only have 6 digits after the decimal point, an afirmation which seems to be incorrect [(programming link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765744/precision-in-c-floats)